# What is the difference between an OutOfMemoryError and a memory leak

Tags: java

I am working on a Java application, whose architecture is something like Java-EE component as one end and C++ component as the other.

When I execute the app continiously I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` in Java heap. I was told this is different from a Java memory leak. If so what is the difference between `OutOfMemoryError` and Java memory leak? And how can I analyse this with a Java profiler?

Comment: there are few different memory leaks in java: heap, direct buffers, perm. gen space, you can be a  victim of any of them. Show the error to get more info. My bet is 'heap', though. In that case you (most likely) get some `static` declared structure and add stuff to it. Alternatively you just execute some DB query that returned too much data and in such case you need to increase the max. memory for available for java. Either way, my recommendations go for reading some book on the topic. Lacking the theory behind is a bad practice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A memory leak in Java is when objects you aren't using cannot be garbage collected because you still have a reference to them somewhere.

An `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown when there is no memory left to allocate new objects. This can be caused by a memory leak, but can also happen if you're just trying to hold too much data in memory at once.

The JDK includes useful tools like jhat and visualVM that allow you to inspect the objects in memory and the references between them. Using these you can often find the objects that are causing the problem.

### Example

Here is a particularly silly memory leak. The old objects are never used, but cannot be garbage collected. While it may seem ridiculous, you can easily create an equivalent leak by mistake in large projects.

```
public class Leaky
{
  private static List<Object> neverRead = new ArrayList<Object>();
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    while(true)
    {
      neverRead.add(new Object());
    }
  }
}
```

This one is not a memory leak, but will usually cause an `OutOfMemoryError` somewhere.

```
public class Allocaty
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    long[] array = new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
    long value = 1L;
    for(int ii=Integer.MAX_VALUE; ii>=0; ii--)
    {
      array[ii] = value++;
    }
    String str = Arrays.toString(array);
    System.out.printf("%d: %s", array.length, str);
  }
}
```

Comment: excellent explanation,Can you give a working example to demonstrate memory leak.what error do i get on console in case of memory leaks ?Highly appreciated if you can elaborate with a working example.

Comment: @Deepak - You don't get any error message until you run out of memory, at which point `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown.

Comment: Thanks a lot this explanation gives answers for lot of questions in my mind(Partiucularly the code examble to differentiate.This one is pretty awesome !!!).

Answer (score 1):

> When i discussed some told like this one is different from java memory leak.If so what is the difference between OutofMemory Error and Java Memory leak.

The two are closely related.  `OutOfMemoryError` is an Error (not an exception, and therefore won't be caught by a `catch(Exception e)` block) that gets thrown when the JVM runs out of memory.  A memory leak is a *possible* cause of the JVM running out of memory.  And in your case as described, I'd say it is the *probable* cause.

(There are other possible causes as well as memory leaks.  You may be trying to run the application on a problem that is too big for the configured heap size.  Alternatively, your might have a bug that causes it to allocate (say) a ridiculously large array.)

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like a bucket for holding water: a leak means it's losing water, but simply being "out of space" means you're trying to put too much into it! So a bucket can be out of space without any question of having a leak.

Comment: Not really. A leak in a bucket generates more space while a memory leak does not.

Comment: True, it is certainly not a perfect metaphor, but one which I felt might benefit the OP who seems to be really just beginning to learn about such things.

Comment: The memory-leak would be the leak in the tube, where you had to put the bucket under it to capture the water. So, leak in the tube => bucket full.